# How is this plastic touch component called?

Tags: touch-panel

I found this TouchPad inside a toy mimicking a smartphone and I am curious about the technology, which seems to be embedded in a simple transfer plastic sheet like those used for projectors.

What should I Google to start my quest?

Thanks. [image]

Comment: It's a [Membrane Keypad](https://www.google.com/search?q=membrane+keypad).

Comment: what is your quest?

Answer (score 0):

The whole assembly looks like a 4x4 keyboard.  To work, the black stuff on the top sheet of clear plastic will need to be conductive plastic.  I'd suggest searching on "conductive ink" or "conductive polymer".

Answer (score 0):

The material is likely "carbon ink", which is an ink that can withstand being exposed to oxygen and will conduct electricity. The keypad will short the comb-structure on key-press.